# ADODB Connection - Webserver doesn't resolve the hostname of the mssql server

Tags: sql-server, connection, hostname

I have a mssql connection resource file as belows:

```
<%
Set Conn01 = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")
Conn01.Open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=forum;UID=forumuser;PWD=forumpass;APP=;Initial Catalog=forumdb"
%>
```

The webserver can interact with the database server when an user logs into the forum BUT I can't ping "forum" machine from the webserver machine. It says "host doesn't resolve." So how am I supposed to know the IP of the database server? There is only a name called "forum" but it doesn't resolve to anything when I attempted pinging the machine.

I need to know the IP address of this data source.

Comment: I'm not an expert on ADODB, but is it possible that 'forum' is an ODBC  connection? Might be worth checking under the ODBC administration settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andy stated, open the Data Sources Administrative Tool and find the "forum" connection either under User DSN or System DSN tab. CLick Configure and look at the name of the server at the bottom. Ping the server from the webserver to resolve its IP.

Answer (score 0):

There could be an ODBC alias configured as well.  On the server's console run cliconfg and look at the Alias tab (I'm that the web server is Windows) for an entry called forum.  That will tell you what server the database is actually on.

That or run "sqlcmd -S forum" (give it username and password as well) and run "SELECT @@SERVERNAME" (or just have your web app connect and disabled the results from "SELECT @@SERVERNAME").